# Windows 7, how to move file from one folder to a different one

Tags: file-transfer

A collection of files that belong in Folder A were mistakenly moved to Folder B.  How do I get them, either one by one, or as a group, out of B into A?  Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Select them all in folder B or otherwise, and either open a new browser window in folder A and drag them there, or drag them into the address bar to go back in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open folder B.
2. In folder B, hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down until step 4.
3. Click once on each misplaced file.
4. Let go of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
5. Right click on one of the selected files.
6. Choose `Cut`.
7. Open folder A.
8. In folder A, right click on some empty space (**not** one of the files there).
9. Choose `Paste`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the folder B.
2. Right-click on the file which you want to move.
3. click on cut option.
4. Go to folder A
5. Right click and click at option paste.
6. your file will be pasted.